# How to publish additional junit5 fail message inside xml report using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, junit5

I'm trying to add additional information's about testcase fail to the xml report:

Building test with gradle parameter

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    reports.junitXml.enabled = true
    // is it gradle side or junit side xml report generator implementation?
    // (does it use LegacyXmlReportGeneratingListener?)
}
```

then implement own extension and use it by `@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)`

```
public class MyExtension implements TestExecutionExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleTestExecutionException(final ExtensionContext context, Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
        context.publishReportEntry("ADDITIONAL_INFORMATIONS", SOME_DATA);
        // (is this call reportingEntryPublished from LegacyXmlReportGeneratingListener?)
        throw throwable;
    }
}
```

But ADDITIONAL_INFORMATIONS doesn’t show anywhere in xml.

I know there is the `org.junit.platform.reporting.legacy.xml.LegacyXmlReportGeneratingListener` but I have found only `org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher` usecase and nothing about how to use it with Gradle.
What is the best way to add an additional message to xml fail entry using gradle/junit5?
Can I add my own `org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener` using gradle?

I'm expect it `<failure message="...here">`.

Using

- junit 5.4.0
- gradle 4.10.2

Answer (score 0):

No, Gradle's reporting infrastructure does not use JUnit's `LegacyXmlReportGeneratingListener`.

In addition, Gradle does not yet include report entries in the reports it generates. See the following Gradle issue for details: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4605